# android studio how to convert string with id to int?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Is there any way to convert string with id (for example: `String id = "R.id.id"` ) to int?

I have tried this:

```
String st = "R.id.id";
int id = Integer.parseInt(st);
```

But it didn't work.

Thanks for help!

Comment: I think what you want is `Resources.getIdentifier()`, but its unclear from your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are asking is completely wrong.

`"R.id.id"` is a `String` that **can't be converted** in a int.

It will always throw a `NumberFormatException` .

Check the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String)):

> Parses the string argument as a signed decimal integer. The characters in the string must all be decimal digits, except that the first character may be an ASCII minus sign '-' ('\u002D') to indicate a negative value or an ASCII plus sign '+' ('\u002B') to indicate a positive value. The resulting integer value is returned, exactly as if the argument and the radix 10 were given as arguments to the parseInt(java.lang.String, int) method.

If the resource used in your `strings.xml` with the same `id` is a integer, you have to use somenthing different:

```
<resources>
    <string name="mystring">12</string>
</resources>
```

Use this code to retrieve a string:

```
String string = getString(R.string.mystring);

try{
   int number = Integer.parseInt(string);
} catch (NumberFormatException nfe){
  //.....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`String` that consists of other than numeric values can not be converted to `int` or into any of the numeric data types. However if a string hold numeric value then you can convert it into `int` or other numeric data types. And the reason for it is every `programming language` has its `syntax` defined, if you want to assign value through character You can do as

```
int variableName = 'a';
or
int variableName = 'b';
```

etc. this is spacial numeric assigning in java `'a'` equals `97` & `'b'` equals `98`.

Or if a string hold numeric value you can convert it as

```
<resources>
    <string name="stringVal">500</string>
</resources>
```

get like this

```
String string = getString(R.string.stringVal);


   int anyName= Integer.parseInt(string);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same thought and unfortunately there isn't really any way to do what you're asking (start with a string, and convert it to an integer ID that you can use with findViewById).

As others have mentioned, there is [Resources.getIdentifier()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources#getIdentifier(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) but that doesn't take in a string as an argument. It doesn't take any arguments, it just spits out an integer that's not tied to anything else. You can of course store that integer in a variable but you won't know what it is ahead of time. You can also look into View Tags which let you add custom tags to views.